# Weblogic-Apache Bridge

Tags: apache, weblogic

I already have a set-up in my production environment and just trying to understand how exactly this works? Please help me understand ,

Set-up :

We have 2 diff kinda set-up. ie, the url https://ddd.myserver.net:111/ABC and https://ddd.myserver.net:222/ . Apache server (ddd.myserver.net)is configured with Listen port 111 to service application ABC and the same server is configured with Listen port 222 to serve application XYZ.
i.e,  https://ddd.myserver.net:111/ABC - Is mapped to the application ABC thats deployed on Weblogic Server.
and https://ddd.myserver.net:222/ - Is mapped to the application XYZ thats deployed on the same Weblogic Server.

Now my question is, the former link (https://ddd.myserver.net:111/ABC) works fine only if the context root(ABC) is appended to the url. IF i try as https://ddd.myserver.net:111/ then the apache_wl.log mentions that there s no page found.
ie.,
**URL::parseHeaders: CompleteStatusLine set to [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]

     URL::parseHeaders: StatusLine set to [404 Not Found]**

But then the second one (https://ddd.myserver.net:222/) just works fine without even mentioning the context root in the url.

Now All I need to know is, how and where is this config likely to be set? Where in the link works without even mentioning the context root?

Thanks.

**[UPDATE]**
I have already looked at the httpd.conf and ssl.conf but couldn't really make out where this has been configured.

**[UPDATE 2]**
Here's the important code snippet, if you require any specific config property pls let me know.
**httpd.conf**

```
Include conf.d/ssl.conf
UseCanonicalName Off
DocumentRoot "C:/Test/WS/ABC/ABC"
Alias /ABC "C:/Test/WS/ABC/ABC"
```

**ssl.conf**

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 111


<VirtualHost *:111>

DocumentRoot "C:/Test/WS/ABC/ABC"
ServerName ddd.myserver.net

ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn

SSLEngine on

<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
  WLLogFile logs/abc_wl.log
  Debug OFF
  DebugConfigInfo OFF
  WebLogicCluster test.myserver.net:7001,test.myserver.net:7003,test.myserver.net:7005
  MatchExpression *
</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your apache bridge config in httpd.conf? The virtual host or location configuration also might help.

Comment: Please check UPDATE 2 for the code snipet

Comment: Is there a `Location /ABC` set in the httpd.conf?

Comment: No JoseK, there are no Location directive set for both ABC and XYZ apps. Its all managed by the MIME type proxy (MatchExpression).